# Check for valid integer

Tags: c

I need a little help with my program  to get a valid integer. I wrote a code which works fine, but if I enter for example 453F, it should display "Invalid int", but my output is 453. Seems it doesn't check for the last int, but I don't know how to make it check and display as invalid input. Here is my code:

```
int main ()
{
    int x;
    getInteger(x);
    return 0;
}

int getInteger (int x)
{
    float check;

    printf ("enter a integer number: \n\n");
    scanf ("%f", &check);
    x = check;
    if (x == check)
    {
    printf("\nYour number is %d", x);
    }
    else
    {
         printf("\nThis is not an integer number, please insert an integer!\n\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to read the value as a string, and then use e.g. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert it to an integer with error checking.

Can be done like this:

```
char str[64];

scanf("%63s", str);

char *endptr;
int value = (int) strtol(str, &endptr, 10);

if (endptr == str)
    printf("Not a valid integer\n");
else if (*endptr != '\0')
    printf("Valid number, but followed by non-numeric data\n");
else
    printf("A valid number: %d\n", value);
```

Your case with `453F` as input would cause the second string to be printed in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's how `scanf` works - it will match what it can and it will leave that `F` in the input buffer.

Other way would be to read string value (using `%s` format specifier) which will accept all characters, and then you can use `strtof` (you can find many examples how to use it) to convert it to the float with error checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can read as a string and check (char by char) the ascii value to be in the right range (48-57).