# check if the value is decimal numbre (not a number as character)

Tags: c

I want to check if the value that the user entered is integer number (**I mean an integer, not a  number as character (like char)**).
I have used `isdigit` function, and `is...` sisters, but does not work good.

**For example:**

```
int digits = 220; // Or scanf("%d", digits); Or any way to take the input from user
if(digits == `integer number`){
   // do things
}else{
   // do things
}
```

Comment: `I have used isdigit function, and is... sisters, but does not work good.`?

Comment: @Acme: I have used `int isdigit (int c)`, but does not work fine.

Comment: if you perform `scanf` with the `%d` modifier, sending it a pointer to `int`, you can't have anything that isn't a decimal number

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for valid integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091356/check-for-valid-integer)

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: Thanks, but I don't care the way to get the input from user, I care check if the user input is integer number or no.

Comment: if you have an `int` it is by definition always an integer number

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: not duplicate, because the solution in that subject say, you must read the number as string, and you can check my subject title to see what I want.

Comment: Well, if you use `scanf` with `%d` as format, it's guaranteed to be an integer. If the user *didn't* enter an integer, then `scanf` would return zero (see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int digits = 220; // Or scanf("%d", &digits);
```

That's it. You are done!

Or, rather, if `scanf("%d", &digits)` returns `1` then an integer has been successfully read and stored in digits.

Note the the declaration `int digits` ensures that only integer values can be stored in `digits`.

So:

```
int digits;

if (scanf("%d", &digits) == 1) {
  // Integer was read successfully from stdin and assigned to digits
} else {
  // Integer was not read. No value was assigned to digits
}
```

Comment: doesn't `scanf` return the number of characters read?  In that case, you should check for `!= 0` instead of `== 1`

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck: good, you are correct. but this depends on if we use `scanf`. so, if we use other way to get the input from user ?

Comment: @Lion King: it does not matter how you write to the `int` typed variable, it will always be an `int`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: @Nathan The return value is the number of values/tokens read.

Comment: @NathanFellman: No, `scanf` returns the number of input items assigned or EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion is completed.

Comment: This method return incorrectly indicate true when the user enters something such as “3.5”. In this case, `scanf` reads the “3”, assigns it to the `int` passed to it (by pointer), and stops at the “.” without indicating an error.